# No setter found for property 'dataSource' in class

Tags: java, spring-mvc

In my `applicationcontext.xml`, I'm getting following error:

> No setter found for property 'dataSource' in class
>   'com.bracketapp.repository.JdbcBracketDetailDao'

I looked at the class and the interface and compared it to others that don't have this problem. i don't see the issue.

here's the full `applicationcontext.xml`:

```
<!-- the parent application context definition for the springapp application -->

<bean id="productManager" class="com.springapp.service.SimpleProductManager">
    <property name="productDao" ref="productDao"/>
</bean>

<bean id="productDao" class="com.springapp.repository.JdbcProductDao">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="academyManager" class="com.bracketapp.service.SimpleAcademyManager">
    <property name="lookupObjectDao" ref="academyDao"/>
</bean>

<bean id="academyDao" class="com.bracketapp.repository.JdbcAcademyDao">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="ageManager" class="com.bracketapp.service.SimpleAgeManager">
    <property name="lookupObjectDao" ref="ageDao"/>
</bean>

<bean id="ageDao" class="com.bracketapp.repository.JdbcAgeDao">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="appUserManager" class="com.bracketapp.service.SimpleAppUserManager">
    <property name="appUserDao" ref="appUserDao"/>
</bean>

<bean id="appUerDao" class="com.bracketapp.repository.JdbcAppUserDao">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="athleteManager" class="com.bracketapp.service.SimpleAthleteManager">
    <property name="athleteDao" ref="athleteDao"/>
</bean>

<bean id="athleteDao" class="com.bracketapp.repository.JdbcAthleteDao">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="beltManager" class="com.bracketapp.service.SimpleBeltManager">
    <property name="lookupObjectDao" ref="beltDao"/>
</bean>

<bean id="beltDao" class="com.bracketapp.repository.JdbcBeltDao">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="bracketManager" class="com.bracketapp.service.SimpleBracketManager">
    <property name="bracketDao" ref="bracketDao"/>
</bean>

<bean id="bracketao" class="com.bracketapp.repository.JdbcBracketDao">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="bracketDetailManager" class="com.bracketapp.service.SimpleBracketDetailManager">
    <property name="bracketDetailDao" ref="bracketDetailDao"/>
</bean>

<bean id="bracketDetailDao" class="com.bracketapp.repository.JdbcBracketDetailDao">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="eventManager" class="com.bracketapp.service.SimpleEventManager">
    <property name="lookupObjectDao" ref="eventDao"/>
</bean>

<bean id="eventDao" class="com.bracketapp.repository.JdbcEventDao">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="resultManager" class="com.bracketapp.service.SimpleResultManager">
    <property name="resultDao" ref="resultDao"/>
</bean>

<bean id="resultDao" class="com.bracketapp.repository.JdbcResultDao">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="weightManager" class="com.bracketapp.service.SimpleWeightManager">
    <property name="lookupObjectDao" ref="weightDao"/>
</bean>

<bean id="weightDao" class="com.bracketapp.repository.JdbcWeightDao">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" 
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<aop:config>
    <aop:advisor pointcut="execution(* *..ProductManager.*(..))" advice-ref="txAdvice1"/>
    <aop:advisor pointcut="execution(* com.bracketapp.service.*Manager.*(..))" advice-ref="txAdvice2"/>
</aop:config>

<tx:advice id="txAdvice1">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="save*"/>
        <tx:method name="*" read-only="true"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<tx:advice id="txAdvice2">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="create*"/>
        <tx:method name="update*"/>
        <tx:method name="delete*"/>
        <tx:method name="*" read-only="true"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="propertyConfigurer" 
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:jdbc.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Check if here is a method `public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource)` in the class `com.bracketapp.repository.JdbcBracketDetailDao`

Answer (score 0):

Does your JdbcBracketDetailDao extend JdbcDaoSupport orNamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport?

Both of these classes give you a setDataSource for free.

Comment: Yes. It extends SimpleJdbcDaoSupport which extends abstract class JdbcDaoSupport.

Comment: Full JdbcBracketDetailDao.java

Comment: Is there another, nested, exception in the stack trace? Can you post your source forJdbcBracketDetailDao?

Comment: I've very much same issue.
Can someone answer this?